# Save video progress

Tags: javascript, html

How can I save the progress of a video in a user's session on my website, like YouTube or Netflix do?

I have a video player created with html and javascript, I share my travels, I would like that when the user enters my website, when he watches a video his progress is saved in his session.

Can you help me? I don't know how to implement it

```js
const playPauseBtn = document.querySelector(".play-pause-btn")
const fullScreenBtn = document.querySelector(".full-screen-btn")
const muteBtn = document.querySelector(".mute-btn")
const captionsBtn = document.querySelector(".captions-btn")
const speedBtn = document.querySelector(".speed-btn")
const currentTimeElem = document.querySelector(".current-time")
const totalTimeElem = document.querySelector(".total-time")
const volumeSlider = document.querySelector(".volume-slider")
const videoContainer = document.querySelector(".video-container")
const timelineContainer = document.querySelector(".timeline-container")
const video = document.querySelector("video")
const controlsContainer = document.querySelector('.video-controls-container');


let controlsTimeout;
controlsContainer.style.opacity = '0';


const displayControls = () => {
  controlsContainer.style.opacity = '1';
  document.body.style.cursor = 'initial';
  if (controlsTimeout) {
    clearTimeout(controlsTimeout);
  }
  controlsTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    controlsContainer.style.opacity = '0';
    document.body.style.cursor = 'none';
  }, 7000);
};



document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  const tagName = document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase()

  if (tagName === "input") return

  switch (e.key.toLowerCase()) {
    case " ":
      if (tagName === "button") return
    case "k":
      togglePlay()
      break
    case "f":
      toggleFullScreenMode()
      break
    case "t":
      toggleTheaterMode()
      break
    case "i":
      toggleMiniPlayerMode()
      break
    case "m":
      toggleMute()
      break
    case "arrowleft":
    case "j":
      skip(-5)
      break
    case "arrowright":
    case "l":
      skip(5)
      break
    case "c":
      toggleCaptions()
      break
  }
})



window.addEventListener('unload', () => {
  const video = document.getElementById('PoS')
  const timestamp = video.currentTime
  window.localStorage.setItem('PoS', timestamp.toString())
})

// to restore the video timestamp
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 const timestamp = document.localStorage.getItem('PoS')
 if (timestamp) {
   const video = document.getElementById('PoS')
   video.currentTime = parseInt(timestamp, 10)
 }
})



document.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
  displayControls();
});

// Timeline
timelineContainer.addEventListener("mousemove", handleTimelineUpdate)
timelineContainer.addEventListener("mousedown", toggleScrubbing)
document.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
  if (isScrubbing) toggleScrubbing(e)
})
document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  if (isScrubbing) handleTimelineUpdate(e)
})

let isScrubbing = false
let wasPaused
function toggleScrubbing(e) {
  const rect = timelineContainer.getBoundingClientRect()
  const percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, e.x - rect.x), rect.width) / rect.width
  isScrubbing = (e.buttons & 1) === 1
  videoContainer.classList.toggle("scrubbing", isScrubbing)
  if (isScrubbing) {
    wasPaused = video.paused
    video.pause()
  } else {
    video.currentTime = percent * video.duration
    if (!wasPaused) video.play()
  }

  handleTimelineUpdate(e)
}

function handleTimelineUpdate(e) {
  const rect = timelineContainer.getBoundingClientRect()
  const percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, e.x - rect.x), rect.width) / rect.width
  const previewImgNumber = Math.max(
    1,
    Math.floor((percent * video.duration) / 10)
  )
  const previewImgSrc = `assets/previewImgs/preview${previewImgNumber}.jpg`
  previewImg.src = previewImgSrc
  timelineContainer.style.setProperty("--preview-position", percent)

  if (isScrubbing) {
    e.preventDefault()
    thumbnailImg.src = previewImgSrc
    timelineContainer.style.setProperty("--progress-position", percent)
  }
}

// Playback Speed
speedBtn.addEventListener("click", changePlaybackSpeed)

function changePlaybackSpeed() {
  let newPlaybackRate = video.playbackRate + 0.25
  if (newPlaybackRate > 2) newPlaybackRate = 0.25
  video.playbackRate = newPlaybackRate
  speedBtn.textContent = `${newPlaybackRate}x`
}

// Captions
const captions = video.textTracks[0]
captions.mode = "hidden"

captionsBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleCaptions)

function toggleCaptions() {
  const isHidden = captions.mode === "hidden"
  captions.mode = isHidden ? "showing" : "hidden"
  videoContainer.classList.toggle("captions", isHidden)
}

// Duration
video.addEventListener("loadeddata", () => {
  totalTimeElem.textContent = formatDuration(video.duration)
})

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", () => {
  currentTimeElem.textContent = formatDuration(video.currentTime)
  const percent = video.currentTime / video.duration
  timelineContainer.style.setProperty("--progress-position", percent)
})

const leadingZeroFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(undefined, {
  minimumIntegerDigits: 2,
})
function formatDuration(time) {
  const seconds = Math.floor(time % 60)
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60) % 60
  const hours = Math.floor(time / 3600)
  if (hours === 0) {
    return `${minutes}:${leadingZeroFormatter.format(seconds)}`
  } else {
    return `${hours}:${leadingZeroFormatter.format(
      minutes
    )}:${leadingZeroFormatter.format(seconds)}`
  }
}

function skip(duration) {
  video.currentTime += duration
}

// Volume
muteBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleMute)
volumeSlider.addEventListener("input", e => {
  video.volume = e.target.value
  video.muted = e.target.value === 0
})

function toggleMute() {
  video.muted = !video.muted
}

video.addEventListener("volumechange", () => {
  volumeSlider.value = video.volume
  let volumeLevel
  if (video.muted || video.volume === 0) {
    volumeSlider.value = 0
    volumeLevel = "muted"
  } else if (video.volume >= 0.5) {
    volumeLevel = "high"
  } else {
    volumeLevel = "low"
  }

  videoContainer.dataset.volumeLevel = volumeLevel
})

fullScreenBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleFullScreenMode)


function toggleFullScreenMode() {
  if (document.fullscreenElement == null) {
    videoContainer.requestFullscreen()
  } else {
    document.exitFullscreen()
  }
}


document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", () => {
  videoContainer.classList.toggle("full-screen", document.fullscreenElement)
})


// Play/Pause
playPauseBtn.addEventListener("click", togglePlay)
video.addEventListener("click", togglePlay)

function togglePlay() {
  video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause()
}

video.addEventListener("play", () => {
  videoContainer.classList.remove("paused")
})

video.addEventListener("pause", () => {
  videoContainer.classList.add("paused")
})
document.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
  displayControls();
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');


*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
/* html{
  display:flex;
} */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  
  
}
video{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.video-container.theater,
.video-container.full-screen {
  max-width: initial;
  width: 100%;
}

.video-container.theater {
  max-height: 90vh;
}

.video-container.full-screen {
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.volver{
  width:38px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 93vh;
  left: 1%;
}
.p{
  margin: 2px 0;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}


  .timeline, .timeline-container{
  margin: 0 1%;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
.full-screen-btn{
  margin-right: 1%;
}


@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  input[type='range'] {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #565656;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    height: 6px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    color: #ff0000;
    margin-top: -1px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    width: 0px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 10px;
    cursor: ew-resize;
    background: #434343;
    box-shadow: -80px 0 0 80px #ff0000;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

}
/** FF*/
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
background-color: #fb0000; 
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
background-color: #5a5a5a;
}
/* IE*/
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
background-color: #ff0000; 
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {
background-color: #5d5d5d;
}
.pause-icon{
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.controls{
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}

.video-controls-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.video-controls-container::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .75), transparent);
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 6 / 1;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.video-container:hover .video-controls-container,
.video-container:focus-within .video-controls-container,
.video-container.paused .video-controls-container {
  opacity: 1;
}

.video-controls-container .controls {
  display: flex;
  gap: .5rem;
  padding: .25rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.video-controls-container .controls button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .85;
  transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.video-controls-container .controls button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.video-container.paused .pause-icon {
  display: none;
}

.video-container:not(.paused) .play-icon {
  display: none;
}

.video-container.theater .tall {
  display: none;
}

.video-container:not(.theater) .wide {
  display: none;
}

.video-container.full-screen .open {
  display: none;
}

.video-container:not(.full-screen) .close {
  display: none;
}

.volume-high-icon,
.volume-low-icon,
.volume-muted-icon {
  display: none;
}

.video-container[data-volume-level="high"] .volume-high-icon {
  display: block;
}

.video-container[data-volume-level="low"] .volume-low-icon {
  display: block;
}

.video-container[data-volume-level="muted"] .volume-muted-icon {
  display: block;
}

.volume-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.volume-slider {
  width: 0;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: width 150ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.volume-container:hover .volume-slider,
.volume-slider:focus-within {
  width: 100px;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.duration-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: .25rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.video-container.captions .captions-btn {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}


.video-controls-container .controls button.wide-btn {
  width: 50px;
}


.timeline-container {
  height: 7px;
  margin-inline: .5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.timeline {
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .5);
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative
}

.timeline::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: calc(100% - var(--preview-position) * 100%);
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  display: none;
}

.timeline::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: calc(100% - var(--progress-position) * 100%);
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.timeline .thumb-indicator {
  --scale: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%) scale(var(--scale));
  height: 200%;
  top: -50%;
  left: calc(var(--progress-position) * 100%);
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: transform 150ms ease-in-out;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}

.timeline .preview-img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  top: -1rem;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  left: calc(var(--preview-position) * 100%);
  border-radius: .25rem;
  border: 2px solid white;
  display: none;
}

.thumbnail-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
} 

.video-container.scrubbing .thumbnail-img {
  display: block;
}

.video-container.scrubbing .preview-img,
.timeline-container:hover .preview-img {
  display: block;
} 

.video-container.scrubbing .timeline::before,
.timeline-container:hover .timeline::before {
  display: block;
}

.video-container.scrubbing .thumb-indicator,
.timeline-container:hover .thumb-indicator {
  --scale: 1;
} 

.video-container.scrubbing .timeline,
.timeline-container:hover .timeline {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../../../../img/logos/HOLLYWOOD (2).png" type="image/x-icon">
  <title>Video Player</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles.css">
  <script src="../script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>  



  <div id="wrapper" id="c-controls" class="video-container paused" data-volume-level="high">
    
    <div  class="video-controls-container">
      <!-- <img class="p" src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/d6xsLOwe76FLpo47zovFkBKpvQg.png"> -->
      <div id="controles">



      <a class="volver" href="#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-arrow-left" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#ff2825" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
        <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
        <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12" />
        <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="11" y2="18" />
        <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="11" y2="6" />
      </svg></a>



      <div class="timeline-container">
        <div class="timeline">
          <div class="thumb-indicator"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="controls">
        <button class="play-pause-btn">
          <svg class="play-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-player-play" width="34" height="34" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#fff" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
            <path d="M7 4v16l13 -8z" />
          </svg>
          <svg class="pause-icon"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-player-pause" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#fff" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
            <rect x="6" y="5" width="4" height="14" rx="1" />
            <rect x="14" y="5" width="4" height="14" rx="1" />
          </svg>
        </button>
        <div class="volume-container">
          <button class="mute-btn">
            <svg class="volume-high-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-volume" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#fff" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
              <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
              <path d="M15 8a5 5 0 0 1 0 8" />
              <path d="M17.7 5a9 9 0 0 1 0 14" />
              <path d="M6 15h-2a1 1 0 0 1 -1 -1v-4a1 1 0 0 1 1 -1h2l3.5 -4.5a0.8 .8 0 0 1 1.5 .5v14a0.8 .8 0 0 1 -1.5 .5l-3.5 -4.5" />
            </svg>
            <svg class="volume-low-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-volume" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#fff" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
              <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
              <path d="M15 8a5 5 0 0 1 0 8" />
              <path d="M17.7 5a9 9 0 0 1 0 14" />
              <path d="M6 15h-2a1 1 0 0 1 -1 -1v-4a1 1 0 0 1 1 -1h2l3.5 -4.5a0.8 .8 0 0 1 1.5 .5v14a0.8 .8 0 0 1 -1.5 .5l-3.5 -4.5" />
            </svg>
            <svg class="volume-muted-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-volume-3" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#fff" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
              <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
              <path d="M6 15h-2a1 1 0 0 1 -1 -1v-4a1 1 0 0 1 1 -1h2l3.5 -4.5a0.8 .8 0 0 1 1.5 .5v14a0.8 .8 0 0 1 -1.5 .5l-3.5 -4.5" />
              <path d="M16 10l4 4m0 -4l-4 4" />
            </svg>
          </button>
          <input class="volume-slider" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="any" value="1">
        </div>
        <div class="duration-container">
          <div class="current-time">0:00</div>
          /
          <div class="total-time"></div>
        </div>




        <p class="p">Orlando / 2022</p>




        <button class="captions-btn">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-copyright" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#fff" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
            <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="9" />
            <path d="M14.5 9a3.5 4 0 1 0 0 6" />
          </svg>
        <button class="speed-btn wide-btn">
          1x
        </button>
        <button class="captions-btn">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-cast" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#fff" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
            <line x1="3" y1="19" x2="3.01" y2="19" />
            <path d="M7 19a4 4 0 0 0 -4 -4" />
            <path d="M11 19a8 8 0 0 0 -8 -8" />
            <path d="M15 19h3a3 3 0 0 0 3 -3v-8a3 3 0 0 0 -3 -3h-12a3 3 0 0 0 -2.8 2" />
          </svg>
        </button>
        <!-- <a href="#" class="se-btn">
          <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-stack-2" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#fff" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
            <polyline points="12 4 4 8 12 12 20 8 12 4" />
            <polyline points="4 12 12 16 20 12" />
            <polyline points="4 16 12 20 20 16" />
          </svg>
        </a> -->
        <button class="full-screen-btn">
          <svg class="open" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-arrows-maximize" width="28" height="28" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#fff" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
            <polyline points="16 4 20 4 20 8" />
            <line x1="14" y1="10" x2="20" y2="4" />
            <polyline points="8 20 4 20 4 16" />
            <line x1="4" y1="20" x2="10" y2="14" />
            <polyline points="16 20 20 20 20 16" />
            <line x1="14" y1="14" x2="20" y2="20" />
            <polyline points="8 4 4 4 4 8" />
            <line x1="4" y1="4" x2="10" y2="10" />
          </svg>
          <svg class="close" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-maximize" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#fff" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
            <path d="M4 8v-2a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2h2" />
            <path d="M4 16v2a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h2" />
            <path d="M16 4h2a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2" />
            <path d="M16 20h2a2 2 0 0 0 2 -2v-2" />
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    
    <video preload id="PoS" src="orlando.mp4">
      <track kind="captions" srclang="es" src="assets/subtitles.vtt">
    </video>


  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Netflix and youtube use `websockets` to acheive what you want, but a REST API should work fine.

```
// you should get your session ID through the session cookie
GET /video/:id => should return the saved timestamp
POST /video/:id => should save the session timestamp
```

You can find the official documentation of an HMTL5 video player [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video).

On your server, set the timestamp in the document head through a script tag in your PHP controller / template :

```
<script>window.SESSION_DATA = { ['my_video_id']: { timestamp: MY_PHP_VARIABLE }}</script>
```

On the document :
You'll need to use eventListeners, something like :

```
var previousTimestamp = 0
function saveVideoTimestamp() {
   const video = document.getElementById('my_video_id')
   if (previousTimestamp !== video.currentTime) {
      previousTimestamp = video.currentTime
      const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
      xhttp.open("POST", "/video/my_video_id", true)
      xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
      xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ timestamp: previousTimestamp }));
   }
}

// restore the video timestamp
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
   const timestamp = window.SESSION_DATA['my_video_id']
   // you could also get it through AJAX here
   if (timestamp) {
     const video = document.getElementById('my_video_id')
     video.currentTime = parseInt(timestamp, 10)
     previousTimestamp = video.currentTime
   }
   // save the timestamp through DB polling (every 10s)
   setInterval(saveVideoTimestamp, 10000)
})
```

This is fairly basic code to get you started, but without more insight on your architecture we won't be able to help.

Comment: This would be stored in the localStorage and is not the session, which means that when you open your session on a different device you will not be able to resume your progress.

I would like to save it in the session, I use php and mysql for the sessions.

Comment: Then create a REST endpoint on your server, and use an AJAX request to send the timestamp instead of saving it in the localStorage. Save the timestamp in your session table on mysql. I will edit my answer

Comment: There are some things I don't understand, where can I contact you directly to send you the whole code?

Comment: please edit your question with a code section

Comment: There's everything I have, html, css and javascript.

Comment: ok, what don't you understand ? You didn't ask anything specific regarding my answer